# Comprehension problem of 世に囁かれる星の数にも届くそれらは、一種の「願望」である。

Tags: meaning, verbs, japanese-to-english

> 世に囁かれる星の数にも届くそれらは、一種の「願望」である。

I have this sentence in Japanese that I'm not sure I completely understand. My own comprehension of the sentence is: "Those who reach the severals stars in the world are the desired...". But there's two parts of the sentence that I don't understand: "世に囁かれる星の数" because of the presence of the passive form of the verb 囁く(to whisper; to murmur​) and "一種の「願望」である" because of the kanji 種.

So I would like to know:

#1: if my translation is accurate or not with the real meaning of the sentence.

#2: the role of 囁かれる and 一種 in the sentence and how they can change the translation I did on the side.

Comment: Please cite a source and give more [context](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2189/what-should-i-do-if-i-was-asked-for-the-context-why-is-it-important). Are you sure you quoted the line correctly? Are you sure it isn't [**一種**の『願望』である](https://syosetu.org/novel/66764/1.html)?

Comment: Oh it's from a light novel (No game No life) and yes I didn't quote correctly you're right. I did the necessary changes. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: Next time, please don't make others search for the original text for the context... Few people want to answer this if they don't even know what this sentence is talking about (i.e., what それら refers to).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need to see the context!

> **『都市伝説』。**
> 　世に囁かれる星の数にも届く**それら**は、一種の『願望』である。
> 　———例えばそれは、『人類は月に行っていない』という都市伝説。
> 　———例えばそれは、ドル紙幣に隠されたフリーメイソンの陰謀。
> 　———例えばそれは、フィラデルフィア計画による時間移動実験。
> 　千代田線核シェルター説、エリア51、ロズウェル事件、etc—–—
> 　枚挙にいとまがない**これらの都市伝説**を眺めれば、明確な法則性が見えてくる。

The それら, "those", refers to 『都市伝説』 = これらの都市伝説, "these urban legends".

世に囁かれる and 星の数にも届く are both relative clauses that modify それら, so:

> 『都市伝説』-- （世*に囁かれる）（星の数にも届く）それらは、一種の『願望』である。
>
> "Urban legends" -- those (which are rumored in the world*) (which are as many as the number of stars) are one kind of "wish".

i.e.

> "Urban legends", which are rumored in the world* and are as many as the number of stars, are a kind of "wish".

<sub>*The [世]{よ}, the world, means [世間]{せけん}, not [世界]{せかい}. [世]{よ}に[囁]{ささや}かれる means [世間]{せけん}で[噂]{うわさ}される.</sub>

Comment: I see, thank you for your answer. Gg for having found the passage in the light novel. But are you sure that 世に囁かれる and 星の数にも届く don't interact with each other?

Comment: @JoDuf はいっ！ 「世に囁かれる+都市伝説」 はいいですけど、「世に囁かれる+星の数」なんて変です。 `Gj for having found the passage` It's not me. Eddie found it and included the link in [their comment above](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/84130/comprehension-problem-of-%e4%b8%96%e3%81%ab%e5%9b%81%e3%81%8b%e3%82%8c%e3%82%8b%e6%98%9f%e3%81%ae%e6%95%b0%e3%81%ab%e3%82%82%e5%b1%8a%e3%81%8f%e3%81%9d%e3%82%8c%e3%82%89%e3%81%af-%e4%b8%80%e7%a8%ae%e3%81%ae-%e9%a1%98%e6%9c%9b-%e3%81%a7%e3%81%82%e3%82%8b/84134#comment136497_84130).

Comment: This makes a lot more sense! それら referring to 都市伝説 makes 囁く a lot more suitable here. @JoDuf sorry for the confusion, I'll be deleting my post :). Also, context is king!

Comment: No problem @Shurim, it's my fault I didn't give all the context. Thank you very much for your efforts and time!

Comment: @Chocolate true. Oh I didn't see the link, thx for the information.